# Android project which was working fine yesterday is now giving errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio v3.2.1, SDK 28
All worked fine yesterday but then the layout previews stopped working (saying `layout_width` and `layout_height`) undefined. Eventually reinstalling fixed that but now I've getting problems with some imports not being recognized `(android.view.View, java.util.List, android.app.Activity)` but most are still OK (android.view.Display, java.util.Map etc.)
Also saying it can't find the Default Activity now although manifest is unchanged and MAIN/LAUCHER are present

Tried invalidating the cache and restarting, reinstalling studio, resyncing with gradle, reinstalling APK, cleaning project but error persists. I do remember updating the android emulator around the time the errors started but not sure why this would affect the editor.

Image:

[image]

```
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View; // This line 'View' is a red error
import android.view.animation.Animation;
```

Oddly enough, it compiles successfully but won't launch.

EDIT: I tried changing the gradle version which did nothing so I changed it back and now it's launching again... Pulling my hair out on this one :/

EDIT: An older project which hasn't been upgraded doesn't have the same errors. I created a new project with one blank Activity which did have the same errors when I tried to add a few imports.

EDIT: I've deleted my SDK folder completely and done a completely fresh install. but still getting the same errors. Is it possible these classes have been deprecated?

EDIT (Temporary Solution) Changed the gradle settings to target SDK 27 and all of the errors have cleared. Hope I don't need a major code rewrite to move up to 28

Comment: If I recall, you might need to tell Studio where your SDK is. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I think it has the right path to the SDK but I'm wondering if the SDK is corrupt. The error in the editor is that the word View is in red. When I type android.view.V then the auto-complete has ViewGroup but not View.

Comment: try to clean your project

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I have used to get the same errors. The problem is that Android Studio recognized the file as a correct file, but overnight, Android Studio might detect errors. Try to re-write your file. If that does not work, think about what you had done before you experienced the error. Sometimes when you change files, it overrides another file, therefore resulting in a error.

Answer (score 0):

When moving to API 28, did you try to convert to `androidx`?

Other things you can try:

- Close Android Studio
- Go to `c:\users\~yourname~\.gradle` and delete the `caches` folder entirely
- Also delete the `build` folder in your `app` directory of your project
- Start Android Studio
- Rebuild your project

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: I didn't make any code changes for androidx but I've been reading the docs for it and it doesn't say View has been deprecated (although a few other functions have been so I would have to make some code changes). I don't remember manually changing to SDK28 so was assuming it happened automatically when I clicked the link in the popup to update the Android emulator. I'll try deleting the files now

Comment: Deleting the files caused a few more errors - now the support.v7 imports have errors so I think this does point to the need for androidx changes when switching to SDK28 although from the documentation, I thought it wouldn't have been necessary